# Binding to a Label not working in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have

In XAML `<Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Id}"></Label>`

In code behind `public int Id;`, in constructor `DataContext = this;`

But the value in Id never appears in the page.

Comment: First, `public int Id;` should be a property, now it's a field.
Second, where is `Id` located? Is it in a ViewModel, or in the codebehind of the page/window?

Comment: Changed to property. It works

Comment: Also, I would suggest moving the `Id` property in a separate ViewModel, to avoid cluttering your page's code behind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `Id` from a `field` to a `property`:

```
public int Id
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

However if you want to change the value of your property at runtime you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`